# emacs theme changes when i moved to zsh from bash

Tags: themes, bash, zsh

I recently shifted form `bash` to `zsh` and also installed `ohmyz`. Since then my emacs theme doesn't work.[image]

the one on the Left is how it looks in bash. On the right, when run on zsh its different.
Thanks,.

Comment: Are `$TERM` environment variables same value ?

Comment: Ha,. thanks @syohex, can you write it as an answer, I shall mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are $TERM environment variables same value ? If its value is different from each other. It causes different looking.